# Criterion for $\mathcal L$-structure to be a model of universal theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

> Let $T$ be a universal (universally axiomatizable) theory of signature $\mathcal L$ without functional symbols. Let also $M$ to be an $\mathcal L$-structure. Prove that if every finite substructure of $M$ is a model of $T$, then $M$ is also a model of $T$.

I need a hint on how to approach this problem because I can't figure out where to start. Thanks!

Comment: Is the signature $\mathcal L$ supposed to be relational? Without some such hypothesis, the result seems to be false. Consider, for example, the structure $M$ consisting of the natural numbers with the constant $0$, the successor function $S$, and the order relation $<$. Then $\forall x\,(x<x)$ is true in all finite substructures, because there are no finite substructures, but it isn't true in $M$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Indeed, it seems there should be an error in the problem statement. I will edit my question.

Comment: OK. By thinking about how an axiom of $T$ could fail to hold in $M$, you get the equivalent problem: If an existential sentence $\sigma$ is true in $M$ then it's true in some finite substructure. Now consider the substructure consisting of witnesses for the existential quantifiers in $\sigma$ (plus the values in $M$ of constant symbols if these aren't considered to be function symbols).

Comment: You can also correct the statement to include functional symbols, by changing the hypothesis for all *finitely generated* substructures.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Am I right that the case when we have infinitly many constant symbols is also bad: assume your contrexample above without $S$ but with constant symbols for each element of the domain. Then the resulting structure doesn't have finite substructures. And then your conterexample works again.

Comment: I think of constant symbols as $0$-ary function symbols. By the way, I think your theorem generalizes to something like "universal-existential sentences are preserved by directed unions".

Comment: The emendation proposed by @Berci is better than mine in the sense that it subsumes mine, because, in the absence of function symbols, finitely generated structures are finite.